# replacing a "," with a "<br />" ... works in jsfiddle, but not on page

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript, so I'm probably overlooking something simple. I've set up the following on jsfiddle: [link to my example](http://jsfiddle.net/fFkcN/1/)

Code is shown here:

```
var wishList = $('#wishList').html();
wishList = wishList.replace(/,/g, '<br/>');
$('#wishList').html(wishList);
```

Here is a link to the live page on which I want the script to run: [script placed at end of document](http://desalonandspa.com/wishlist/bob-davis)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the code doing on your site?

Answer (score 4):

It's failing because you have other errors on the page and it's stopping execution of JavaScript code before it gets to you.  Check your page in the debug window (F12 on Chrome and IE)